# How to write raw query in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am beginner in Laravel.I can write query in raw PHP.Now i want to write it in Laravel framework.I have read documentation and tried so far:

**In Raw PHP:**

```
SELECT count(*)/(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2016-01-01 00:00:00',now())+1) as avg from buyer  where created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
```

**Tried with Laravel:**

```
public function index(){
    //
    $yrUserReg = DB::table('buyer')
                    -> SELECT (DB::raw (count('*')/("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2016-01-01 00:00:00',now())+1"))) 
                    -> AS ('avg') 
                    -> WHERE ("created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'");
   return view('userflow',compact($yrUserReg));                 
}
```

But it throws me an error: **`Division by Zero`**.I can not find any solution of this.
Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: You forgot to wrap the expression you're passing to DB::raw in quotes. That's executing as php. And you've mangled the quotes inside the SQL count

Comment: Use `$result= DB::select("");` write your raw code inside `select();`

Comment: Beware, also, that those methods(`select()`, `as()` and `where()`) with those spaces and such capitalized are never going to work.

Comment: Yeah they will @phaberest. Otherwise the complaint would be about syntax errors or invalid method names. Function/method names are case-insensitive in php and the spaces are fine too - white space is collapsed anyway.

Comment: Thanks @clive, something I didn't know!

Comment: @AHJeebon its working but how to fetch data i am trying `$resultyr = mysqli_fetch_array($query);` but its throws error `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given`

Comment: search for that error that are a ton of questions on that

Comment: Yes!! got it.Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete built query:

```
$yrUserReg =  DB::table('buyer')
                ->select(DB::raw("(count('*')/(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2016-01-01 00:00:00',now())+1)) as avg"))
                ->where('created_at', '>=', '2016-01-01 00:00:00')
                ->get();
```

Comment: your missing a ) after the ->select